# Make multiple directories from Mediainfo information to put music in

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, multimedia

I have a bash script that goes through my music folder, gets all the song metadata with [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) and is intended to make folders out of all the artists' names, but it fails.

This is the code so far:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd Music/
for i in "$(ls -b | grep -v /)"; do
    info=$(mediainfo $i)
    artist=$(echo "$info" | grep "^Performer" | awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i)printf $i""FS ; print ""}')
    mkdir "$artist"
done
```

For some reason, it seems to go through all the songs first and then tries to make a directory with all their names combined; my intent is to create a directory for the performer found by Mediainfo in each music file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Iterate over files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash) without `ls`.

```
for i in ./Music/*; do
    info=$(mediainfo "$i") # fixed to "$i"
    artist=$(echo "$info" | grep "^Performer" | awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i)printf $i""FS ; print ""}')
    mkdir "$artist"
done
```